# Mapping specific subfields from JSON to Java Class properties on Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON like this:

```json
[
  {
    "flags": {
      "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/cx.png",
      "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/cx.svg",
      "alt": ""
    },
    "name": {
      "common": "Christmas Island",
      "official": "Territory of Christmas Island",
      "nativeName": {
        "eng": {
          "official": "Territory of Christmas Island",
          "common": "Christmas Island"
        }
      }
    },
    "region": "Oceania",
    "population": 2072
  },

...
]
```

It is a list of countries I'm getting from [here](https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,region,population,flags). I am mapping that JSON to a Java class as below:

```java
public class Pais {

  @SerializedName("name")
  @Expose
  private String nome;

  @SerializedName("region")
  @Expose
  private String regiao;

  @SerializedName("population")
  @Expose
  private int populacao;

  @SerializedName("flags")
  @Expose
  private String bandeira;
}
```

And then I used GSON to serialize the whole thing with

```java
    executor.execute(() -> {
      Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
      String URL = "https://restcountries.com/v2/all?fields=name,region,population,flag,numericCode";
      InputStream inputStream = conexao.obterRespostaHTTP(URL);
      Auxiliador auxiliador = new Auxiliador();
      String textoJSON = auxiliador.converter(inputStream);

      Gson gson = new Gson();

      if (textoJSON != null) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Pais>>() {
        }.getType();
        paises = gson.fromJson(textoJSON, type);

        handler.post(() -> {
          paisAdapter = new PaisAdapter(this, paises);
          listView.setAdapter(paisAdapter);
        });
      }
    });
```

But the thing is, the fields 'name' and 'flags' will be parsed as objects, since they have other parameters inside of them, right? Is it possible to do something like mapping the  "png" field inside the "flags" field from the JSON directly to my class parameter "bandeira," for example?

I've tried changing the `@SerializedName` notation to things like `@SerializedName("flags.png")`, but it didn't work. I imagine there is a specific way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to transform the JSON structure before converting to the POJO.  You can try JSON library *Josson* which make use of *Jackson* instead of *Gson*.

```
public class Pais {
    private String nome;
    private String regiao;
    private int populacao;
    private String bandeira;
}
```

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
ArrayList<Pais> paises = Josson.fromJsonString(textoJSON)
    .getJosson(
        "map(nome: name.common," +
        "    regiao: region," +
        "    populacao: population," +
        "    bandeira: flags.png)")
    .convertValue();
System.out.println(paises);
```

**Output**

```
[{nome=Christmas Island, regiao=Oceania, populacao=2072, bandeira=https://flagcdn.com/w320/cx.png}]
```

Comment: That's really cool! I'll have to test it over the weekend, because I was in a hurry and implemented it the hard way: with some internal private classes representing objects so GSON could map things correctly lol.